# jquery toggle (show/hide) based on selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I want to create animation based on jquery, below is my code;

```
>items=document.querySelectorAll("#customers td span");
[<span alt=​"  02,Counter,11,2013-04-06 14:​59:​16">​  02​</span>​, <span>​11​</span>​, <span alt=​"  02,Counter,11,2013-04-06 13:​22:​19">​  02​</span>​, <span>​11​</span>​]
>item=items[0]; // it has a parent tag <tr> i want the whole row to blink (both spans)
<span alt=​"  02,Counter,11,2013-04-06 14:​59:​16">​  02​</span>​
>tm=item.attributes.getNamedItem("alt");
alt=​"  02,Counter,11,2013-04-06 14:​59:​16"
>dtm=tm.value.split(',')[3];
"2013-04-06 14:59:16"
```

or in JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setInterval(function(){
        $("#customers, td, #span").each(function(){
            if($(this).children("span").attr("alt")!=null)
                var dt=new Date($(this).children("span").attr("alt").split(",")[3]).getTime();
                    if(dt>$.now()-10*1000){ //am i right here??
                        console.log("animating");
                        $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow");
                        $(this).parent().fadeIn("slow");
                    }        
       });
    },1000);
});
```

every second i want to check for each element in items; if dtm > current time - 10 seconds, then it should hide after 500 ms and should show after 500ms.

the code above that i have will only blink one span, i want both of the elements to blink.. and this check should continue each 1 second.

can any one help me..

Thanks..

Comment: If you are able to use jQuery why are you messing around with `querySelectorAll` and `attributes.getNamedItem()`? You need to loop through the items, so `$("#customers td span").each(...` should take care of the looping and then `$(this).attr("alt")` gets the attribute with the date for the current item. Is the problem how to take the date as a string (after the `split()`) and turn it into an actual date to compare with the current time?

Comment: i have already done it, now the problem is the smoothness of animation..

Comment: the above code is running in chrome but not in firefox.. can some body help??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861643/jquery-multi-selector-each-not-a-function-firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my final code;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    window.setInterval(function(){
        $("#customers, td, span").each(function(){
            if($(this).children("span").attr("alt")!=null){
                var dt=new Date($(this).children("span").attr("alt").split(",")[3].replace(/-/g,"/")).getTime();
                if(dt>$.now()-20*1000){
                    console.log("animating");
                    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500,"linear");
                    $(this).parent().fadeIn(500,"linear");
                }
            }
        });
    },1100);
});
</script>
```

Comment: added `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to `#customers,td,span,tr` which improved the performance of the animation a bit..