# jquery $(multi selector).each() not a function firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I am having the code below in page;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setInterval(function(){
        $("#customers, td, #span").each(function(){
            if($(this).children("span").attr("alt")!=null)
                var dt=new Date($(this).children("span").attr("alt").split(",")[3]).getTime();
                    if(dt>$.now()-10*1000){ //am i right here??
                        console.log("animating");
                        $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow");
                        $(this).parent().fadeIn("slow");
                    }        
       });
    },1000);
});
```

this code works fine on chrome, but does not work on firefox;
firefox saying `TypeError: $(...).each is not a function`.

Can any one help me??

Comment: Can you please paste the entire html code at jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net? It will help to understand what's missing, but my guess is that you haven't included a reference to jquery.js

Comment: Could it be that you have *another* JS framework loaded besides jQuery? Does it work when you replace all `$` with `jQuery`?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ekibet/1/edit

Comment: tried replacing $ with jQuery, still not working..

Comment: Works fine here. Have you added jQuery to the jsbin?

Comment: the jsbin doens't include definition of `init()`

Comment: just added jQuery to the jsbin..

Comment: jsbin.com/ekibet/7/edit works in chrome but not in firefox with me..

Comment: it looks like `new Date()` is not working in firefox..

Comment: here is the final version;
http://jsbin.com/ekibet/9/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like `new Date()` is not working in firefox.

the date was;

```
new Date("2013-04-07 15:39:17");
```

i updated it to;

```
new Date("2013/04/07 15:39:17");
```